# Sort A-Z but keep Products/Variation Integrity

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I am working on a price sheet that has products with variations to that product underneath.
It has 15,000 rows and I would like to sort in alphabetical order.

However doing so breaks the product/variations, so you wont know what variations are with what product.
I have color coded all the products as well as the variations.

**What I need is the Products to be sorted A-Z, along with keeping the variations underneath it.**

Sorting breaks the product/variation setup.

Comment: what about using a pivot table for that in a tabular format?

Comment: Yes, second that as @DavidLeal said, using `Pivot Table` will be the best, simplest and easiest way to do.

Comment: I don't know what a Pivot table is. Can someone explain?

Comment: @glennkline please check the solution I provided that doesn't require a Pivot Table. You can find a lot of documentation on the internet about Pivot Tables. If not as an alternative is my answer under Office 365, I assume you don't have any excel version constraints as per the tags listed in your question. Please next time provide sample data in *table markdown* format, there is no need to provide a screenshot to illustrate the issue and it helps others to reproduce your problem. Thanks

Comment: I was thinking about the Pivot Table approach, it won't work as we expect, because of the way the input data is organized. You need to create a helper column, and for that then you can sort it manually without using a Pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an excel formula, here is a possible approach. In cell `D2`, put the following formula:

```
=LET(rng, A2:B9, types, INDEX(rng,,1), names, INDEX(rng,,2),
  groups, SCAN("", names, LAMBDA(acc,name, IF(acc="",name,
    IF(XLOOKUP(name, names, types)="Product", name, acc)))),
 DROP(SORT(HSTACK(rng, groups), COLUMNS(rng)+1),,-1)
)
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

`groups` name contains an array of the same number of rows of `rng`, having the product name for the product and its variation. Then we just need to sort by this intermediate column created the input range.

**Note**: This solution assumes the first row always starts with a `Product`, not a `Variation`.

Adding a helper column `C` is another alternative. For example, put in `C2` the following formula and drag it down:

```
=IF(A2="Product", B2, C1)
```

then you can use this column for sorting. This is exactly what the `SCAN` formula does, but generating the values programmatically.

Comment: I get a #SPILL! error. I switched to office 365. Still same Error.

Comment: yes, it is an issue @glennkline, you don't have such functions. Here is the [list of functions by release](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates.htm). Then the best approach would be to use a Pivot Table

Comment: Here is the screen shot. https://imgur.com/a/U9WvN4E

Comment: The formula works with my input data, you need to update the `rng` value to your specific range. I updated the formula, so there is no need to update other portions of the formula, just the input range `rng`.

Comment: So I need to change the rng number to what exactly. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlbTJFYL-3NWpE_PZXY0JIGVFj7w?e=ySXCam

Comment: Yes, you have a big file, your range is `A2:G15696` this is what you need to put in the formula. Please make your file editable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249675/discussion-between-glenn-kline-and-david-leal).

Answer (score 0):

Make a new column in front of A (or wherever, doesn't really matter, visually is easiest imo): "Sort"

```
=If(B2 = "Product"; C2; A1+1)
```

Copy paste as Values and then sort descending. You can delete/hide the A column after then. Making "keys" is the easiest way to sort/organize/check for doubles.

Comment: Where do I put this?  =If(B2 = "Product"; C2; A1+1)

Comment: If you did add the column in front of A, then in A2 and then filldown.

Comment: I'm getting a formula error. I put the formula in A2. Looks like it does not like "Product"

Comment: Is your original column A containing formulas itself? Or is "Product" and "Variation" just plain text?